# How to join results from two tables in one output file?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MySQL DB; table1, table2.

Both of them have a single column (float) values. It's actually a dump from our research project which produces a single value result.

And many of these values get repeated and sorting and filtering them in Python would be cumbersome, so I though perhaps dumping them in a table in DB would be quicker.

So the end result from the SQL query is the following grouped by the value:

```
value    table1_count   table2_count
1.0          0               1
1.1          1               3
2.1          4               5
```

The query I am coming up with is the following:

```
select everything.value, everything.count1, everything.count2
from
((
select X as value, count(*)  from table1 
) union all (
select X as value, count (*) from table2 
)) everything
group by everything.value
into outfile "/count";
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do counts by group in the inner queries, since you're defining the groups in the outer query.  This should be simpler:

```
select everything.value, count(*)
from
(
  select X as value from table1
    union all 
  select X from table2
) everything
group by value
into outfile "/count";
```

Also here's some trivia: when you use `UNION`, you need to define column aliases only in the first query unioned.

---

Re your comment.  Here's one solution:

```
select everything.value, sum(t = 'success') as s, sum(t = 'failure') as f
from
(
  select X as value, 'success' as t from table1
    union all 
  select X, 'failure' from table2
) everything
group by value
into outfile "/count";
```

This uses a trick in MySQL that boolean expressions return 0 for false or 1 for true.  So when you sum up a bunch of expressions, you get a count of the rows where the expression is true.  (Don't rely on this trick in other brands of SQL database.)

Comment: Thanks Bill...

But it doesn't answer my question...

In your reply, you have one outer count that is combining the count from both table 1 and table 2; i need to keep the count separate for each table as one represent success and the failure, so they can't be combined in the outer query..

Any suggestions?